# Method from another class does not work entirely when called

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have this code:

```
class Matplotlib_figure(QMainWindow):
  minimumCoords = None
  maximumCoords = None
  initial_marker = None
  final_marker = None
  limite = None

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff to draw a matplotlib figure

  def minimumLimit(self):
    self.cMinL = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.select_minimumLimit)
    self.limite = "minimum"

  def select_minimumLimit(self, event):
    if event.button == 1:
        self.clearMarker()  #This is another method that i call

        Matplotlib_figure.minimumCoords = None
        Matplotlib_figure.minimumCoords = event.xdata

        if Matplotlib_figure.minimumCoords <= Matplotlib_figure.maximumCoords or Matplotlib_figure.maximumCoords == None:

            marker = self.axes.axvline(event.xdata,0,1, linestyle='dashed',
                linewidth = 2, color = "green" )    
            self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
            Matplotlib_figure.initial_marker = marker


class Data(QDialog):
  minimum = None
  maximum = None

  def __init__(self, parent):
    QDialog.__init__(self, None, QWindowsStayOnTopHint)
    uic.loadUi("", self)

  def show_lines(self):
    SelectData.minimo = self.lineEdit.text()
    SelectData.maximo = self.lineEdit_2.text()

    Matplotlib_figure.minimumCoords = float(SelectData.minimo)
    Matplotlib_figure.maximumCoords = float(SelectData.maximo)

  #Here is where i want to call a method in the Matplotlib_figure class
    view = Matplotlib_figure()
    view.minimumLimit()
    view.maximumLimit()
```

The problem comes in the Data class. When i want to call the `minimumLimit`method in the `Matplotlib_figure`class (from show_lines in Data class), it does not trigger the `figure_canvas.mpl_connect`method, and `select_minimumLimit`method does not work.

What am i doing wrong? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key issue comes from this note in the [matplotlib event handling docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#event-connections):

> The canvas retains only weak references to the callbacks. Therefore if a callback is a method of a class instance, you need to retain a reference to that instance. Otherwise the instance will be garbage-collected and the callback will vanish.

So you have created a new `view` in the `show_lines` method, but this is a local variable. When the function returns, the variable goes out of scope and python will probably try to delete it. Normally if you save a reference to a method off, then the method retains the object it is a method for, and this would not happen, but because `mpl_connect` only takes a weak reference to the function **it does not retain `view`**, and therefore when the `show_lines` returns, the method is lost too, and so the callback will revert to doing nothing.

You can probably fix this by rewriting `show_lines` to save the view off, something like:

```
def show_lines(self):
    SelectData.minimo = self.lineEdit.text()
    SelectData.maximo = self.lineEdit_2.text()

    Matplotlib_figure.minimumCoords = float(SelectData.minimo)
    Matplotlib_figure.maximumCoords = float(SelectData.maximo)

    #Here is where i want to call a method in the Matplotlib_figure class
    self.view = Matplotlib_figure()
    self.view.minimumLimit()
    self.view.maximumLimit()
```

Now the `Matplotlib_figure` instance will be retained as long as the `Data` instance is.

[Previous answer based on error in question kept below]

I don't know the QT framework or the matplotlib APIs very well, but it looks to me that you've created an instance of `ViewWidget`, which is an entirely separate class (subclass of the QT `QMainWindow` class, if I recognise that, which is an entirely different python module) from `Matplotlib_figure`. Therefore I would expect when you call `minimumLimit()` that you'd get an `AttributeError` exception, and I wouldn't expect it to call your method. If you want that you'll have to create an instance of it and call that:

```
view = Matplotlib_figure()
view.minimumLimit()
view.maximumLimit()
```

Without more context of where your `ViewWidget` comes from it is hard to understand how you think this should work. It's also a bit odd that you are creating a `matplotlib` figure that is a subclass of the unrelated `QMainWindow` class. What are you trying to achieve with this? Could you provide some more context for the code?

Comment: Sorry, "ViewWidget" was a typo. I´ve already edited. What i need to do, is to connect my `Data`class to the `minimumLimit`method in ` Matplotlib_figure`class. But, when i tried to do it, i can not make `mpl_connect`to trigger.

Comment: Did you try out my suggestion / get it to work? I'm pretty sure the problem was the weak-reference and not saving the `view` off.

Comment: Yes, i tried your suggestion and it worked, So sorry for not accepting your answer before. I made a trip those days and I forgot to. Thank you so much for helping me and for remind me too .